# JPA Entities give stackoverflow error when onverting to JSON, but not when using POJO

Tags: java

I'm working with JSON and JPA, and have main method, to do some testing with my objects.

whenever I try to convert a Java Entity to a JSON string a get a stack overflow error as such

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(cus1)
```

if I instead use a regular POJO in this case as a DTO, I don't get an error. But how come it makes a stack overflow error, when I use an entity class?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByAge", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.age = :age")})

public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String name;
private int age;
@JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private City city;
//getters, setters and constructor
```

Comment: Does city has a list of Customers?

Comment: Yes it has a realationship of OneToMany, so City hsa one Customer, and City has a collection of customers

Comment: update your question with all classes and getters and setters.

Comment: It's possible that `toString` from City is calling Customer, and calling city again, causing the stackoverflow

Comment: did you need to serialize the customers in the City object? If not, you can ignore using `@XmlTransient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to City serializing the Customer, and a Customer serializing the cities again, causing the `StackOverflowError`.

If you are not using the cities object in the `Customer` entity, just ignore the field during the json serialization.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<City> cities;

}
```

or vice versa, using `@XmlTransient` in the `private City city;` field.